# Select the same css className that exist across multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add click event to a nav  links for different pages of my portfolio site(homepage, about page and contact page). This click event is to highlight the currently selected/clicked nav link.  this navigation is the same for all pages and have the same class names. Am using event delegation and propagation to attach the event listeners. Am also using webpack as my build tool to dynamically attached the css and javascript

```html
<nav class=" main-nav" >
  <ul class="main-nav__list">
    <li class="main-nav__item">
      <a href="#!" class="main-nav__link ">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-nav__item">
      <a href="#!" class="main-nav__link">CVitae</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-nav__item ">
      <a href="#!" class="main-nav__link">Hire Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
let mainNavList = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav__list");

for (let i = 0; i < mainNavList.length; i++) {
  mainNavList.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if ((e.target.tagName = "A")) {
      let clicked = e.target;
      let current = document.getElementsByClassName(".active");
      if (current.length > 0) {
        current[0].classList.remove("active");
      }
      clicked.classList.add("active");

      console.log(e.target);
    }
  });
}
```

The code above works fine on a page document(without the queryselectorall) but for multiple pages that has the same html navigation, it work for just the first click event of the about page and nothing else.
Any help with be apprecited. Thank You

Comment: `mainNavList` is Node List Elements. Use `mainNavList[i].addEventListener("click", function(){})` instead.

Comment: tried that but got the same behaviour - it works on the index.html page but not the other pages